# Buggy behavior using requestAnimationFrame

Tags: javascript, svg, requestanimationframe

I've wrote a useful library to draw and animate the stroke of SVG paths: segment. You can [check it on github](https://github.com/lmgonzalves/segment).

Some time ago I've replaced (accepting a Pull Request) the `setTimeout` calls with `requestAnimationFrame`, to speed up the animation in modern browsers, also using the [polyfill](http://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/) provided by Paul Irish.

Now I'm experimenting a buggy behavior with `requestAnimationFrame` calls when I tried to animate multiple `paths` with a very low delay among them.

I've prepared 2 demos to show the behavior with both `setTimeout` (working properly) and `requestAnimationFrame` (buggy behavior). Check it please:

- [`setTimeout` Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/orvtzk5t/1/)
- [`requestAnimationFrame` Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/gjpx0s9L/2/)

In the `requestAnimationFrame` Demo, I've modified a bit my library to print in the console some useful info, where you can see the buggy behavior:

```
(function calc(){
    // Checking if it's the first element, the buggy behavior happens in the firsts elements
    if(that.class === 'first'){
        console.log('calc');
    }

    // Some code here that can break the recursive loop and stop execution of calc function

    if(that.class === 'first'){
        console.log('calc call');
    }
    that.timer = window.requestAnimationFrame(calc);

    // More code here
})();
```

According to the previous code, after every 'calc call' message should appear a 'calc' message. But that is not what I can see, at least in Firefox and Chrome. This is the console output most of times:

```
calc
calc call
calc
calc call
```

I really have no idea what's going on, so any help is welcome :)

Comment: I'm confused.  You say "after every 'calc call' should get a 'calc'". But your code does this opposite.  The output looks correct.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau Sorry you don't understand, I'll try to explain differently. In the console, you must first receive a "calc", so far everything perfect. Later, a message 'calc call' should appear, and as subsequently called back to the `calc` function must appear another 'call' message (first sentence in `calc` function). The last console output can not be 'call calc', it has to be 'calc', because the only way to stop the loop is placed where say `// Some code here`. Hopefully it's clear now, and sorry for the delay to answer.

Comment: If you need to exit the loop function, just call `return`. If `requestAnimationFrame()` is not called again, then the loop will stop there.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau I'm actually exit the loop with an `if` condition, that is not the problem. The problem is that I'm calling `window.requestAnimationFrame(calc);`, and in the second call it's not running the `calc` function, because the 'calc' message is not shown.

Comment: Can't reproduce in FF44.0.2

Comment: @SergeSeredenko Just update my FF to that version, and still the same. Sometimes it works fine, but most of times it's buggy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The buggy behavior here is being caused because both `timeoutID` and return value from `requestAnimationFrame` are being saved into the same variable. Saving them in different variables will fix the issue.

Here is a codepen

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KzPboY?editors=0010